# How to get all variables from a string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, unity-game-engine

I get a string from UnityWebRequest containing all the information I need.
The problem is that `UnityWebRequest.downloadHandler.text` returns a string.

How do I get all variables, like all the names, put into an array of strings?

Below is an example of some code I get.

```
"{'id': 1, 'name': Bob, 'age': 25},{'id': 2, 'name': Mark, 'age': 32},{'id': 3, 'name': Simon, 'age': 16}";
```

Comment: Parse it as `Json`.

Comment: Agreed, you need to parse it as `JSON`. Tell us if you can't.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen How do I do this? I have the Newtonsoft.Json and Json NuGet packages, and still can't seem to use Json.Parse...

Comment: @KianHeinsbæk: Since that string isn't strictly valid Json it can be a bit tricky. You need to reformat it to be able to parse it correcrly.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen this was just an example, the string I have is perfectly formatted for JSON, but the problem is I can't seem to figure out how to get ahold of a JSON class that contains the Parse function.

Comment: @KianHeinsbæk: Use `Newtonsoft.Json` and the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method. You'll need to define the object class first though. See my answer as an example.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen I get this error: "JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'FolderData[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly."
Do I HAVE to list all the properties in the string into the class? If I only need the name, can the Data class only contain that, or does it have to include properties for all the values in the string?

Comment: @KianHeinsbæk: No you don't have to specify every property. The error message indicates that you are trying to serialize an object as an array which of course you can't. Look at the Json and check that your c# object is correct.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen I still can't get the right result.. My code right now is:
string folderInformation = allFoldersReq.downloadHandler.text;

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FolderData>(folderInformation);

        Debug.Log(obj.Id);
        Debug.Log(folderInformation);

Can you spot any errors? My class FolderData just contains two properties now (id and name).

Comment: @KianHeinsbæk: How does the received data look?

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen It looks emtpy. When I debug the object, it just says FolderData, and if I try to show the id (Obj.id) it says 0.

Comment: @KianHeinsbæk: I mean `allFoldersReq.downloadHandler.text`.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen This is what I get (the two previous comments). Some information is sensitive, so it is replaced by multiple x's.

Comment: @KianHeinsbæk: That is valid Json so I suspect there is something wrong with your C# classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out.
The problem was that my JSON class wasn't written probably. I copied the string UnityWebRequest sent me and saved it to a text file. I then imported this text file into Unity assets folder and from there I used Visual Studios "Paste Special" and that created my JSON class for me.

From there I used JSONUtility.FromJson to read UnityWebRequest and then I could get all the information I needed from the string.

Thanks to Sani Singh Huttunen for providing me clues to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should parse it as `Json`.
But that can be a bit tricky since the data isn't strictly valid Json.
You need to do some reformatting first:

Here is a simple example:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var jsonString = "{'id': 1, 'name': Bob, 'age': 25},{'id': 2, 'name': Mark, 'age': 32},{'id': 3, 'name': Simon, 'age': 16}";
        jsonString = jsonString.Replace("\'", "");
        jsonString = Regex.Replace(jsonString, @"\w+", @"""$0""");
        jsonString = "[" + jsonString + "]";

        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data[]>(jsonString);
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```